# Differences in separation of static and stateful code in different languages

Tags: java, php, python, perl, static

I've noticed that Java, Python, Perl, and Haskell/Clojure have distinctively different treatment of static functions.  In particular,

**1) What are the idiomatic differences in the way static functions are implemented and utilized in different languages.**

**2) Do some of these languages have "more complete" separation and support of static vs statefull methods than others?**

For example :

In clojure, all functions are, essentially, static - allowing for extreme modular composability , not associated with any thing in the object-ether. Clojure-functional programming can be described to java programmers as similar to static functions.

Meanwhile, in traditional idiomatic Java, there is often a mixture, where object-oriented features maintain internal state, relying on external static methods for certain, often stateless transformational operations.

Then, there is the scripting world : I've noticed in Perl and Python that the concepts of differentiating static vs stateful code are not stressed quite as much (UPDATE:As per comment - maybe this is due to the multi-paradigm nature).

And finally, we have the object-oriented breed of PHP-5 developers, who seem to code similarly to java developers in its their treatment of static vs stateful (object scoped) functions.

Any other insights into the differences in how different programmers, from different backgrounds, treat static functionality would really help me to review code with a few PHP/Perl developers that I work with.

Comment: *(not an answer to your question hence the comment)*... The way your question is formulated makes it sound like all non-static method are stateful.  This is not at all the case: if you want you can, for example, program in Java by using interfaces and stateless implementations of these interfaces (it's just one example, you can also have stateless abstract classes extended by stateless class, etc.).  I know that using Java using, say, mostly immutable objects and stateless classes ain't the most common but it definitely can be done.

Comment: The `static` keyword doesn't say anything about the functions statefulness, and/or that differs between languages. A `static` PHP/Java method can keep just as much state as any other piece of code.

Comment: to add onto to @deceze, static functions can modify static variables. Essentially, this means globals.

Comment: Should this be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You are mixing the idea of `static` (with a largely language dependent definition) with the idea of `pure functions` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).  You should edit your question to clarify which you mean.

Comment: Yeah thats true - in java, "pure" functions are addressed by making functions static .... But all static functions are not necessarily pure .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant distinction may be the programming paradigm emphasized by language. [Functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) languages such as Haskell & Clojure aim to eliminate side effects and emphasize determinism; encapsulating mutability or state in thinks like monads. This is in contrast to [Imperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) languages. Perl & PHP are multi-paradigm languages, so it is possible to implement imperative styles such as procedural and object oriented coding, or even emulate functional styles.

In collaborating with imperative programmers it might be worth focusing on loose coupling and side effect free design patterns such as [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).